# How to build an executable with ffmpeg and lame

Tags: python, macos, ffmpeg

I've written a (stand-alone?) Python app that I would like to distribute. My app is a simple app but it uses ffmpeg and lame lib. I want this to also be included in my executable. As in, ffmpeg and lame should also be installed when my app gets installed. Any idea on how to go about this? I'm targeting Mac OSX users for now.

Answer (score 0):

See this wikipedia [List of installation software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software).

I have used Install4j (costs $2K) and IzPack (free); both require the JVM, and a few days each of testing and experimentation. There are other options that don't appear to require JVM.

While your current target is OSX, if you are considering multi-platform it is well worth testing on Linux and Windows from the start.

How to go about it? Build up a sample installation, then use the tool to bundle it up and install on the target machine. And test, test, test.

Spend some time thinking about what kind of future change you want to support (that's where the multi platform bit helps), and what minimum OS version and machine config you require.

Finally: make sure you are complying with the licenses of both ffmpeg and lame, and the tool you use.

Comment: Is it alright to include a script to install ffmpeg and lame on the end user's computer if he or she doesn't have it already ?

Comment: Yes. They are part of your product, and the license you provide must include the licenses for ffmpeg and lame. Just be upfront so that your users know what they are getting.